# Using "forbidden" class in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

My employer needs a Java class that extends `org.eclipse.rse.core.subsystems.SubSystem`, for an Eclipse plugin. Unfortunately the access rules on the library that implements it (`org.eclipse.rse.ui_3.3.318.201404091445.jar`, if it helps) marks everything "forbidden" that it doesn't expressly allow, and that class isn't expressly allowed.

I can change the access rule to allow access to that class, but will that cause problems when the plugin is installed on another machine?

Comment: If who ever wrote it was cool with the class being extended I doubt that they would have gone around marking everything `forbidden`. Changing 3rd party source files can potentially cause unspecified behaviour, we could be detrimental to whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: The [documentation page](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Frse%2Fcore%2Fsubsystems%2FISubSystem.html) explicitly says that the class was "designed to be subclassed," which is what baffles me.

Comment: Looking at the link I'm seeing that `SubSystem` is an abstract class which means that you will need to extend it at some point or use one of its subclasses. On another note, it could be that the documentation is not in sync with the code. In cases such as this I would follow what the code says. At most, what you can do is contact who ever wrote it, if possible.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: In Eclipse, the Properties for a project, the "Java Build Path" page, the Libraries tab: expand any of the "Plug-in Dependencies" (or even the "JRE System Library" items and you'll see several options, including "Access rules." Using such rules, you can mark different items as "accessible," "discouraged," or "forbidden."

Comment: @npinti Yes, I'm trying to extend it.

Comment: I'm a little confused here ... I've developed a plug-in that extends that very same class with no problems at all.  It's been working fine for years. My plug-in is based on IBM Rational Developer for i 9.1.

Comment: @david: I'm confused about it too. Can't figure out why it's not accessible here. This is for another version of IBM Rational Developer.

Comment: @HeadGeek which version of RD?

Comment: @david Rational Developer for System z, version 9.1.

Comment: Maybe open a PMR with IBM?  That class **shouldn't** be restricted or forbidden. I know it's not in RD for i... and I'm using the exact same JAR that you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse help clearly documents that

> References to types from a forbidden package result in class loading
>   errors at runtime.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Faccess_rules.htm

So it is not advisable at all to override this.

Comment: *sigh* Thanks, hadn't seen that.